# What is the origin, and correct spelling of, "shtook"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, palatalization

I quite frequently use a word that sounds like "shtook", to mean, trouble with the law or other authorities, as in, "You'll be in dead *shtook* if you do that" or "you'll be in real *shtook* if you don't finish your homework", but I have never seen it written, and don't know how it is spelt.

Can anyone shed some light on the matter. A search [like this](http://us.yhs4.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?fr=altavista&q=dictionary+shtook) doesn't get very far; the real dictionaries don't recognise it and the Urban Dictionary [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shtook) has only a typically obscene interpretation not in the least bit like I remember it.

Comment: In my upbringing (North London Jewish) it was always _shtukh_ with a fricative at the end, not a plosive. When I heard _shtuk_ I assumed it was speakers for whom the /x/ was alien, like those who pronounce _loch_ like _lock_. I always took it to be a Yiddish word, but never explored it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English has this:

> **shtuck; schtuck; schtook; stuk** *noun* trouble. Not Yiddish despite appearances, although probably formed on the Yiddish model of a reduplicated word commencing with a ‘sh’ sound, in which case ‘shtuck’ is a variant of ‘stuck’ (in a difficult situation) UK, 1936.

The OED agrees, "origin unknown: app. not a Yiddish word".

Comment: Could that be of German origin (as in "Stück  Hölle") ?

Comment: @Alain: speculation. Polish has *sztuka* meaning "art". Now what? (^_^)

Answer (score 5):

I've done a little bit of research about this "shtook" slung term and it looks like the **Yiddish origin** cannot be ruled out so easily.

To sum it up, I've come to the conclusion that the most probable origin is an abbreviation of the phrase **shtuck dreck** which means **piece of crap** and it comes from the Jewish community.

Here is some supporting evidence.

**1**. Wikipedia has an list of article titled "[English words used by English-speaking Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish_words_used_by_English-speaking_Jews).  One entry reads:

  > **shtick dreck** – literally "a piece of dirt" (see Dreck), but usually
  >  applied to a person who is hated
  >  because of the antisocial things he
  >  has done: "He's a real **shtuck dreck**."
  >  Possibly shtick dreck: a piece of
  >  crap. Cf. **German Stück Dreck**.
  NB:  In German:
  *Ein Stück*
  means "a piece of" and
  *Dreck*
  in Yiddish means "excrement".  
  Hence the often seen
  **deep**
  in "in
  *deep*
  shtuck".  Speaks for itself.

**2**. The [slang dictionary](http://www.slang-dictionary.com/definition/in-shtukshtookstookschtuk.html) also postulates a Yiddish origin.

  > **shtuk/shtook/stook/schtuk**  in trouble. A very widespread expression which moved from a
  >  restricted demi-monde and theatrical
  >  usage to common currency in the
  >  mid-1960s, partly through its use in
  >  the entertainment media. Shtuk in its
  >  various spellings is Yiddish for
  >  difficulties. ‘In shtuk’ often refers
  >  to financial difficulties.

**3**. I also found in the usenet archives at Google (formerly dejanews) the expression [used](http://groups.google.com/group/soc.culture.jewish/browse_thread/thread/395a665c4ac921b2/305f1483f8c379fe?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=shtuck#305f1483f8c379fe) in the *soc.culture.jewish* news group:

  > They really do stick to their **shtuck drek**.

**4**. One possible reason why the word might be deemed as non Yiddish is because it is supposed to come from London (as opposed to NY).  However I also [found this interpretation](http://www.learnglish.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/english/2970/Schtuck-shtuck-shtook):

  > ...are ubiquitous in the East End (London)
  >  but seem to have been particularly strong around
  >  the Bethnal Green/Spittalfields market areas.
  >  There is (or was) a strong Jewish immigrant
  >  presence in that quarter. It seems quite
  >  possible to me that 'shtook' is a joint
  >  Cockney-Yiddish development

So despite the Partridge Slang dictionary I'd go for the Yiddish/German origin.

Comment: Kudos for the leg work, but I don't follow the leap from *shtick dreck* to *in deep shtuck* in your NB. Frankly, you seem to have confused yourself there. It's *Dreck* that means "dirt, crap"; not *Stück*. So "in deep shtuck" means "in deep piece", which doesn't make any sense. Note also the unexplained (and IMHO inexplicable) jump from *shtick* to *shtuck*. That transition makes no sense phonologically. It's very typical of Yiddish to have an I where German would have an Ü. An U is a completely different sound in both languages. In short: that's way too much speculation for my tastes.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you mean the Yiddish term *[shtuk](http://www.slang-dictionary.com/definition/in-shtukshtookstookschtuk.html)*:

> **in shtuk/shtook/stook/schtuk** in trouble. A very widespread expression which moved from a restricted demi-monde and theatrical usage to common currency in the mid-1960s, partly through its use in the entertainment media. Shtuk in its various spellings is Yiddish for difficulties. ‘In shtuk’ often refers to financial difficulties.

Comment: As there is debate on the issue of Yiddish origin for the term I have decided to undelete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Poking around Google hits for "shtook" I found "schtuck" which is just "stuck" with a goofy pronunciation.

> Haha, now you're schtuck.

"Shtook" and its many variants seem common enough to credit but my childhood was probably using "stuck".

Answer (score 1):

Clive James in The North Face of Soho mentions the first time he heard this word when it was used by television producer Paul Knight in the 60s in London. He used to say they were in 'deep shtuk' although this was later amended to 'deep Took' as their somewhat unimpressed  boss was Barry Took.

Answer (score 1):

I recall members of my family (Romany background, Cockney slang influence?) referring to a *schtook*, a piece of cloth which was tied around the neck, which makes sense in that if you were in schtook you'd be up to your neck in trouble.

Comment: I think that's probably a [stock](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stock) (meaning 24). Could well be the (or an) origin.

Answer (score -1):

just a suggestion     We English have words that are considered unsuitable in polite company and make last second alterations to the word ending to avoid offence.

eg    hell     becomes heck
      what the devil    becomes what the dickens
      shit     becomes sugar

Could shtook be another example - a last second substitution for shit

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer. The stupid site policy probably does not allow you to place a comment with your initial reputation, however still this your remark is not an answer to the OP.

Comment: It's highly unlikely, surely, that a word beginning /ʃ-/ would be replaced with one beginning /ʃt-/.

Answer (score -2):

It means "fuck", pure and simple.  I used to date a girl and as we went out the door her father said, "Remember no kuppa (canopy used in Jewish wedding), no shtuker".

Comment: That's **[shtup](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shtup)**, not "shtuck".  It even rhymes with chuppah - "No chuppah, no shtuppe".  "Shtup" actually literally means "to push"; I particularly enjoy another phrase "to shtup oneself in die hoyecheh fenster" (to push oneself in through the high windows) - meaning "social climbing".